# Python pandas. Replace values in columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose i have a DataFrame objects like this:

```
age_diff    result
       1         0
      -1         1
       0         1
```

I want to replace negative values in column `age_diff` by applying to them `abs` function. Also, if value in `age_diff` is changed, value in column `result` should be switched(if it was 0 then to 1, else to 0).

After this transformation DataFrame, shown above, should look like:

```
age_diff    result
       1         0
       1         0
       0         1
```

Can, anyone, point me to how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) + [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) + [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
print (df)
   age_diff  result
0         1       0
1        -1       0
2        -1       1
3         0       1


mask = df['age_diff'] < 0
df['age_diff'] = df['age_diff'].abs()
df['result'] = df['result'].mask(mask, df['result'].map({0:1, 1:0}))
print (df)
   age_diff  result
0         1       0
1         1       1
2         1       0
3         0       1
```

Another solution - instead map cast to `bool` and invert by `~`:

```
mask = df['age_diff'] < 0
df['age_diff'] = df['age_diff'].abs()
df['result'] = df['result'].mask(mask, ~(df['result'].astype(bool)))
print (df)
   age_diff  result
0         1       0
1         1       1
2         1       0
3         0       1
```

Comment: Super, glad can help. Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach you can take is applying a function:

```
def magic(row):
    if abs(row['age_diff']) != row['age_diff']:
        row['age_diff'] = abs(row['age_diff'])
        row['result'] = 1 - row['result']
    return row

df = df.apply(magic,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the signs of `age_diff` with `np.sign` and manipulate from there.

```
s = np.sign(df.age_diff.values)

df.age_diff *= s
df.result -= (s == -1)

print(df)

   age_diff  result
0         1       0
1         1       0
2         0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one liner solution using lambda to get abs of age_diff and then change sign of result if age_diff is negative.

```
df.apply(lambda x: [abs(x.age_diff),abs((x.age_diff<0) - x.result)],axis=1)
Out[165]: 
   age_diff  result
0         1       0
1         1       0
2         0       1
```